# polynomials with leading coefficient unit are cancellable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, euclidean-domain

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit.

The general statement of Euclidean Division in $R[x]$ is the following.
If $f, g \in R[x]$ and $g \neq 0$ with the leading coefficient of $g$ being a unit, then $\exists q, r \in R[x]$ such that $f = qg + r$ and either $r = 0$ or $\deg(r) < \deg(g)$.

I have already shown the existence of $q, r$, and I am now trying to show their uniqueness. So for any $q', g' \in R[x]$ I want to start by showing that if $f = qg + r = q'g + r'$ then $q \neq q' \iff r \neq r'$. To do that I think I need to prove the following statement: if $f, g, h \in R[x]$ such that $f \neq 0$ and the leading coefficient of $f$ is a unit, then is it true that $fg = fh \implies g = h$. But I am struggling with the last part.

Comment: If $f$ is as you specified in the end, can its product with any nonzero polynomial be the zero polynomial?

Comment: @TedShifrin I see now, units are non-zero-divisors.

Comment: With $\,\ell=$ lead coef: $\,0\!=\!fg\Rightarrow 0\! =\! \ell(fg)\!=\!\color{#c00}{\ell(f)}\ell(g)\Rightarrow \ell(g)\!=\!0\,(\Rightarrow g\!=\!0),\,$ by $\color{#c00}{\ell(f)}\,$ cancellable. $\ \ $